# How to write my own request body parsing method to override the default one in Apache2::Request

Tags: apache, mod-perl

I am using mod_perl to handle file upload (multipart/form-data).
When files get uploaded, Apache2::Request automatically parse the request body and store the content into a tmp file.

My question is that is there any easy way I can write my own request body process method which can override the default one since I need to do additional processing on the file body such as encryption etc.

So far the only way I found is to use UPLOAD_HOOK, but in the doc, it said:

"Sets up a callback to run whenever file upload data is read. This can be used to provide an upload progress meter during file uploads. Apache will automatically continue writing the original data to $upload->fh after the hook exits."

which means the default input handler will process the file again after upload_hook which generate a second tmp file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've resolved this by now but i'll post anyway.
You can easily subclass Apache2::Request, see:  [subclassing Apache2::Request](http://httpd.apache.org/apreq/docs/libapreq2/group__apreq__xs__request.html)
Here is a CPAN module for another example:
[Apache2::REST::Request.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~jeteve/Apache2-REST-0.07/lib/Apache2/REST/Request.pm)